# Android AsyncTask nullpointer exception

Tags: json

Hello I am working on a translator application. This app takes string from webview with clipboard.getText().toString(); I would like translate this selected word with yandex api. I created AsyncTask class to take translated word from api.

```
public class Translate extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
TranslatedWord trWord = new TranslatedWord();
private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "text";

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(args[0]);
    return json;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    try {
        JSONArray result = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
        String text = result.getString(0);
        trWord.setTrWord(text);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I should insert selected word and translated to database on same table. I am doing this on following code.

```
private static String TRANSLATE_URL = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?" +
        "key=trnsl.1.1.20171218T092308Z.2e90b7fad1cf523b.a2696fb34d9d70f427cad15c9ee664230c048054" +
        "&lang=tr&text=" + selectedWord;

    final ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            selectedWord = clipboard.getText().toString();

            translate.execute(TRANSLATE_URL);

            translatedWord = trword.getTrWord();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copy:\n" + selectedWord, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            WordsDbHelper helper = new WordsDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT engWord FROM words; ", null);
            boolean titlePresent = false;

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String recorded_title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("engWord"));
                if (recorded_title.equals(selectedWord)) {
                    titlePresent = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is already same word!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            if (!titlePresent)
            helper.createWord(new Words(selectedWord, translatedWord));
        }
    });
```

I have some problems with taking translated word. I am taking this error. I need some help. Please help me.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.AsyncTask com.ermanelm.redler20.Translate.execute(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like **translate** object is null, Try replacing,

```
translate.execute(TRANSLATE_URL);
```

with

```
new Translate().execute(TRANSLATE_URL);
```

Comment: This time I have another problem. I need access the String text value on onPostExecute from onPrimaryClipChanged() like   translatedWord = trword.getTrWord(); But it does not work. I have another class to keep string and there is set get methods. How can I access the text variable?